# Comparing 2 universal properties.

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces, quotient-group, universal-property, quotient-set

Here is the first universal property and the map required to prove it:

> [image]

And here is the second universal property:

> [image]

**My questions are:**

1- Are they the same or not? I am guessing that both of them are universal properties for the quotient but why $A$ needed to be Abelian in the second and how this is compensated in the first?

2- Is the map used for proving the first can also be used for proving the second?

Could anyone help me in answering those questions please?

Comment: They are both universal properties, but they refer to different properties.  Said another way, they are both manifestations of the same phenomenon (image of $G$ under an adjoint functor) but relative to different categories.

Comment: What are those different categories? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: The latter is the category of abelian groups; the former is a slightly more complex category involving the subgroup $H$.

Comment: And I am guessing that the map used to prove the first is the same as the one we can use to prove the second .... am I correct?@ArturoMagidin

Comment: It is a particular type of quotient, so yes. What they are saying is that $[G,G]$ is contained in the kernel of any map into an abelian group, and is universal with respect to that property.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin is it giving us any information about any of the groups $G/[G,G]$ or $G$ being Abelian.

Comment: It is telling you that $G/[G,G]$ is the “largest” quotient of $G$ that is abelian (so $[G,G]$ is the smallest normal subgroup such that the quotient is abelian). $G$ is abelian if and only if $[G,G]$ is trivial, if and only if the canonical map $G\to G/[G,G]$ is the identity.

Comment: I’ll write up something later...

Comment: Have you any familiarity with category theory?

Comment: @BillDubuque  Not that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are similar, in that the second is a special case of the first, with the added information about the fact that the subgroup $[G,G]$ is connected to abelian groups (in some perhaps mysterious way). The map you get in the second instance is indeed the map that you would have in the first example, if $[G,G]$ plays the role of $H$. It just so happens that anytime you have a map whose kernel contains $[G,G]$, the image of the map will be abelian.

---

Where these “universal properties” come from... I’m going to borrow the presentation framework from George Bergman’s [*An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions*](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egbergman/245/), as I’m teaching a course out of it right now.

Fix your group $G$, and a subgroup $H$ (not necessarily normal). Let us consider all the morphism $f\colon G\to K$ to groups that have that property that $f(h)=f(e)$ for all $h\in H$ (that is, $H\subseteq \mathrm{ker}(f)$). There are many reasons you may be interested in such maps.

Note that if we have such a morphism $f$, and $g\colon K\to M$ is any group morphism from $K$ to another group, then we will automatically get a new morphism from $G$, namely $g\circ f\colon G\to M$. This map will also satisfy that $(g\circ f)(h)=(g\circ f)(e)$ for all $h\in H$, since $g$ must send $e_K$ to $e_M$.

So one may wonder if there is a “universal” example of a map $p$ from $G$ to a group $\mathfrak{G}$, with the property that (i) $p(h)=p(e)$ for all $h\in H$; *and* (ii) any map $f\colon G\to K$ with $f(h)=f(e)$ for all $h\in H$ can be obtained by composing $p$ with a map from $\mathfrak{G}$ to $K$. That is, we would like a pair $(\mathfrak{G},p)$ with the following universal property:

1. $p\colon G\to \mathfrak{G}$ is a morphism;
2. $p(h)=p(e)$ for all $h\in H$; and
3. If $f\colon G\to K$ is any morphism into a group such that $f(h)=f(e)$ for all $h\in H$, then there exists a unique morphism $g\colon \mathfrak{G}\to K$ such that $f = g\circ p$.

The answer is “yes”; such a “universal pair” is given by taking $\mathfrak{G}=G/N$, where $N$ is the normal closure of $H$ in $G$; and $p\colon G\to G/N$. is the canonical projection, $p(x)=xN$. Then the map $g\colon G/N\to K$ is given by $g(xN) = f(x)$.

---

Now let us consider a related problem: say we are interested in maps from $G$ to abelian groups. Again, if $f\colon G\to A$ is a map from $G$ to an abelian group, then any morphism $g\colon A\to B$ of abelian groups will give rise to a new morphism from $G$ to an abelian group by composition, $g\circ f\colon G\to B$. Is there a “universal pair” $(A,p)$ such that

1. $A$ is an abelian group and $p\colon G\to A$ is a morphism.
2. If $B$ is any abelian group and $f\colon G\to B$ is a morphism, then there exists a unique morphism $g\colon A\to B$ such that $f=g\circ p$.

Again, the answer is “yes”: the universal pair is the group $G/[G,G]$ and $p\colon G\to G/[G,G]$ is the projection onto the quotient. One may be led to this group by noting that any map $p\colon G\to A$ form $G$ to an abelian group must satisfy
$$p(xy)=p(yx)$$
and hence that $e = p(yx)^{-1}p(xy) = p(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)$. That is, the elements of $[G,G]$ must lie in the kernel of any such map; this already tells us from the first universal property that the maps will factor through $G/[G,G]$. And since this group is abelian, it must be the “universal example” of a map into an abelian group. That is, we can justify the fact that $(G/[G,G],p)$ is a universal pair into abelian groups by using the first universal property of the quotient.

---

In fact, the latter can be viewed in the context of categories: you have the collection of all abelian groups sitting inside the collection of all groups. Moreover, any “abelian group” morphism between abelian groups is a morphism of them as groups, but more importantly, any group group morphism between them is also what one might call an “abelian group morphism”. In the language of category theory, the collection of all abelian groups is a “full subcategory” of the category of abelian groups.

But in fact there is more: the existence of a “universal example” of a map from an arbitrary group to an abelian group says that we have a way to go from “group” to “abelian group” with the following property:

> If $G$ is a group and $A$ is an abelian group, then there is a natural bijection between the group morphisms from $G$ to $A$, viewing $A$ as a group, and the abelian group morphism from $G/[G,G]$ to $A$. That is,
> $$\mathbf{Group}(G,i(A)) \cong \mathbf{Ab}(G/[G,G],A).$$
> where $i(A)$ means that we view $A$ as a group, “forgetting” that it is in fact an abelian group.

This is an instance of something called an “adjunction”. It is a key concept in category theory, especially as it relates to algebras. We can view the abelianization $G/[G,G]$ as the realization of this adjunction. One can also view the first universal property as an instance of an adjunction, though the category is more complicated and perhaps looks more unnatural, so I won’t go into them (especially if you are not very familiar with Category Theory).

Comment: I do not understand this statement "It just so happens that anytime you have a map whose kernel contains $[G,G]$, the image of the map will be abelian.
" .... can you explain more please?

Comment: I am proving that the map is well defined for the second statement and I have a problem in explaining why $$\phi(g_{2})\phi(g) = \phi(g_{2}) . 1$$ in the second statement. Could you help me please in explaining why this is true in the second statement?

Comment: Here is the whole steps I am doing  So, $$\tilde{\phi}(g_{1}G^{'}) = \phi(g_{1}) = \phi(g_{2}g) = \phi(g_{2})\phi(g) = \phi(g_{2}) . 1 = \phi(g_{2}) = \tilde{\phi}(g_{2}G^{'}). $$
      
      Where the first equality by definition of $\tilde{\phi},$the second equality by $(1),$ the third equality because $\phi$ is a homomorphism, the fourth equality because $g \in G^{'}$ which means that $g = [x,y] = xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ for some $x,y \in G$ and since $A$ is Abelian by the given then $G^{'} \subset$Ker $\phi$

Comment: Also, Here are the details of $(1)$ I mentioned in my previous comment. So, suppose that $g_{1}G^{'} = g_{2}G^{'},$ then multiplying both sides by $(g_{2})^{-1}$ from the left, we get   $$(g_{2})^{-1}g_{1}G^{'} = G^{'},$$Which means that $(g_{2})^{-1}g_{1} \in G^{'}.$ i.e. there exists $g \in G^{'}$ such that $(g_{2})^{-1}g_{1} = g,$ which means that $$g_{1} =  (g_{2})g \quad \quad (1)$$ And $G^{'}$ is $[G,G].$

Comment: It’s really hard to respond to a series of four long comments....

Comment: @Smart20: Note that if $f$ is a morphism, and the kernel contains $[G,G]$, then for any $x,y\in G$ you have $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy\in\mathrm{ker}(f)$. So $f(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)=1$. That means that $f(x)^{-1}f(y)^{-1}f(x)f(y)=1$, so $f(x)f(y)=f(y)f(x)$. That is, the image is abelian.

Comment: @Smart20: “**The** map”, “In the *second* statement”. Sorry, but I don’t read minds. I don’t know what “the” or “second” refers to in your second comment.

Comment: @Smart20: $[G,G]$ is the subgroup **generated** by all elements of the form $[x,y]$. It need not equal the set of all such elements; you need to take products of such elements and their inverses (though $[x,y]^{-1} = [y,x]$, so it is enough to just take products”.

Comment: The second refers to "the second universal property in my posted question"

Comment: @Smart20: The fact that the map $G/[G,G]\to A$ is well-defined follows from the fact that the map in the first property is well-defined. The whole point of having that first theorem is to not have to re-prove it every time you need it. $[G,G]$ is a normal subgroup, contained in the kernel, so the map factors. Doing the proof again for *that* particular normal subgroup makes the effort of proving the theorem in the first place a waste of time.

Comment: By the map I meant $\tilde{\phi}(gH) = \phi (g)$

Comment: But I do not have the first universal property as a given. I only have to prove the second universal property without being given the first one. I by myself accidently found the first UP so I decided to mimic its proof to prove the second UP, but I got stuck in the well definedness. Specifically why $\phi(g)$ should be equal 1 in the second universal property.

Comment: @Smart20: If $f\colon G\to A$ is a morphism to an abelian group, then $f([x,y])=e$ for each $x,y\in G$. Therefore, if $g\in[G,G]$, then $g$ is a product of things that map to $e$, hence $g$ maps to $e$.

Comment: I know that maybe $A$ being abelian is the reason for $\phi(g) = 1$, but how? I am unable to specify educated reason for that.

Comment: @Smart20: Why did you accept the answer, given that you clearly did not find it in any way clarifying? The reason $[x,y]$ lies in the kernel is that $f(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy) = f(x)^{-1}f(y)^{-1}f(x)f(y) = f(x)^{-1}f(x)f(y)^{-1}f(y) = e$.

Comment: I am sorry I read your comment just now but I have a question: $A$ is the group that its element commutes not the $x$ and $y.$ so how that leads to that $f([x,y]) = e$?

Comment: Ohhh I understood just now. Thank you so much!